# Is it possible to "embed" the id of the current user in a fragment of thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a header which is present on all pages, on the header there is a button which moves to the own page of the current user.
How to "sew" into this header, so to speak, the id of the user, so that the fragment is immediately passed with the id of the current user.
There is such a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<header th:fragment="title">
    <div class="logo">
        <a th:href="@{/}">AccountHub.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="reg-log">
        <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAnonymous()')}">
            <a th:href="@{/account/login}" style="margin-right: 70px">Вход</a>
            <a th:href="@{/account/registration}" style="margin-right: 70px">Регистрация</a>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${!#authorization.expression('isAnonymous()')}">
            <a th:href="@{/users/{id}(id=${})}">
                <img class="profile-image" src="https://mobimg.b-cdn.net/v3/fetch/75/754da20683ab4a8f859dfa0a7ba0f9ce.jpeg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</html>
```

I want to pass the id to this line

```
<a th:href="@{/users/{id}(id=${})}">
```

But I do not understand, whether it is possible to do it, so that once passed to this fragment and everywhere to use it, and that it was not necessary to pass to each page separately, where there is a given header, id through Model.
If there is no such a possibility, how to make more competent, more correct?

I don't even know if it's possible to do that